# how to debug browser caching issue?

Tags: apache, cache-control

I have configured apache http with some cache settings.  However, it does not seem to work properly and the browser seems to keep fetching the file as if it's not cached.

I tried to debug it by fetching the header.

```
$ curl -skI https://whatever-url-it-is/some-script.js

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 15 Sep 2019 05:35:08 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.6.40
Last-Modified: Sun, 02 Jul 2017 10:52:25 GMT
ETag: "152ba-5535372162c40"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 86714
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public
Expires: Tue, 17 Sep 2019 05:35:08 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/javascript
```

The Cache-Control header seems to be correct.  The Expires header looks a little odd but according to this page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) the Expire will be ignored given that Cache-Control is there.

What else can I do to debug this issue?  Any idea is very well welcome.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Never mind.  I didn't realized that "Disable Cache" was turned on in Chrome.  User error :-)